# SQL query - find values that meet m conditions out of n

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to find values that meet any m conditions out of given n conditions? For instance, if there are 10 conditions, and I want to find values that meet **any** 2 of them.

Comment: Hint : Logical `OR`.

Comment: You may want to add a concrete example with sample data to your question as to make it more "answerable".

Comment: Simplified, e.g. 5 conditions instead of 10. [mcve]

Comment: I would create a counter to count the number of conditions that are met, then show only the records if it maches counter > m. Use the if/else. Probably use a cursor but this is bad practice

Comment: Exactly 2, or 2 or more?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 4):

Use `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause, 1 for each condition like this:

```
WHERE 2 = 
  CASE WHEN <condition1> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN <condition2> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN <condition3> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  ..........................................
```

You can change the `=` sign to `>` or `<` to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There is. It's not gonna be pretty though.

Start with your conditions as `SELECT` expressions.

```
select T.*,
       case
         when T.SOME_NUMERIC_COLUMN > 0 then 1
         else 0
       end                       IS_POSITIVE,
      (select sign(COUNT(*))
       from   SOME_OTHER_TABLE
       where  parent_id = T.ID)  HAS_CHILDREN
       ...
from   SOME_TABLE  T
```

Design these expression in such a way that you get 1 when a condition is met and 0 when it's not.

Then sum up the score and add a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT R.*,
         IS_POSITIVE + HAS_CHILDREN + ...        SCORE
  FROM (...) R)
WHERE SCORE > 2
```

Of course you're gonna pay a hefty price in performance for this. You won't be able to use your conditions directly to limit the resultset so I'd expect the execution plans to be extremely disappointing. That said, it's not like what you have in mind is a standard task for RDBMS so it should be enough for a proof of concept.